# How to toggle IMG remove and append using one button?

Tags: jquery, image, dom, append, element

I am trying to create a button, that when clicked, inserts an image as a list item, and then when clicked again removes it from the list.

I have achieved this so far using the hide / show method which is great. But doing it like this means the element still exists in the DOM.

I would like to completely remove the image from the DOM when clicked, and then re-add the same image back to the DOM when it’s clicked again.

I’ve looked at the jquery .remove, .append and .detach events but I’m struggling to figure it out. Although I can use these methods to adjust paragraphs, lists, and divs, I can’t figure out how to make one specific button grab one specific list item with a specific image in it to achieve the hide and show effect.

Perhaps a list is not best suited for this, but it was my initial choice for testing due to its UL parent.

Is this possible? Any education is welcome.

```
<div id=“toggletom”>this is my button</div>

<ul>
<li id="tomato"><img src="tomato.jpg"></li>
</ul>

<script>
$( "#toggletom" ).click(function() {
 $( "li" ).remove( ":contains('img src=tomato.jpg')" );
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is 100% possible to do, however we need to see your code in order to help you debug it.

Comment: Thanks Rory, I’ve just added my test code. the syntax is wrong I think. One alternative I have considered is to use onclick on the div and call the function. But any help is much appreciated. I’d like to understand it really.

Comment: Fix the quotes you're using in `id=“toggletom”`. Why do you need to completely remove and then re-add the image to the DOM?

Comment: @Littlemug can you do one operation? I mean can you do either only remove or only append?

Comment: Once remove how would you know what image to add? And if you re adding back the same image anyway why not just hide and show. You are not saving anything by removing and adding the image back because you'd have to store the image somewhere for reference to add back.

Comment: @Evik Ghazarian i’d really like the div that’s acting as a button to make an image disappear and reappear each time it’s clicked. But instead of using hide and show, to actually remove the image from the DOM. As the image is a list item, the idea I had was to remove the list item when clicked, then insert it back when clicked again. The problem is how to grab the correct list item, I think.

Comment: @Littlemug I understand, but does it work when you only use remove? does it remove? And why are you insisting on using remove

Comment: Not so far I’m afraid. I’m also thinking I’d require an if else statement to do this properly. I have the logic, but I’m very new to JS: If > 
List does not contain “tomato” 

> use .append and add new list item called “tomato”,

Else > use .remove
and remove “tomato” list item,

Comment: @Nawed Khan good question. When using hide and show I’m just changing the display of the element. With what I am trying to achieve that means that a list of fruits with a button for each fruit, would always show in the same position when visible. Yes the list items would bump up against each other and different items could be displayed, but you would never be able to add tomato’s first then everything on top of it as it’s at the top of a static list in the html. Tomatos would always appear at the top.

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole number of ways you can do this. You mentioned wanting to `.remove()` versus `.hide()`. You also want to restore the content later verus `.show()`.

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function saveHtml(item) {
    var h = item.prop("outerHTML");
    item.parent().data("lastChild", h);
  }

  function restoreLast(lObj) {
    var h = lObj.data("lastChild");
    if (h != undefined) {
      $(h).appendTo(lObj);
    }
  }

  function addTom(lObj) {
    var li = $("<li>", {
      id: "tomato-" + ($("li", lObj).length + 1),
      class: "image item"
    }).appendTo(lObj);
    $("<img>", {
      src: "https://i.imgur.com/ROLJaSi.jpg"
    }).appendTo(li);
  }

  function removeLast(lObj) {
    saveHtml($("li:last-child", lObj));
    $("li:last-child", lObj).remove();
  }

  $("#toggle-tomato").click(function() {
    var t = $(this).text();
    if (t.indexOf("Hide") >= 0) {
      // Action: Hide Last Tomato
      removeLast($("#image-list"));
      $(this).text("Show Last Tomato");
    } else {
      //Action: Show Last Tomato
      restoreLast($("#image-list"));
      $(this).text("Hide Last Tomato");
    }
  });

  $("#add-tomato").click(function() {
    addTom($("#image-list"));
  });
});
```

```css
#image-list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#image-list .item {
  padding: .25em;
}

#image-list .image img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle-tomato">Hide Last Tomato</button> <button id="add-tomato">Add Tomato</button>

<ul id="image-list">
  <li id="tomato-1" class="image item"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ROLJaSi.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Removing a jQuery Object is very easy using `.remove()`. If you want to put something back after it's been removed, you have to know what that something was. This means storing the HTML or a template of the element being removed someplace. Since we're working with a list, we can just stuff it in with the list. I used `.data()` to tack it on to the parent element.

You can adapt this to work in lots of ways and much like much of jQuery, you want to have a Setter and Getter function (Show/Hide). Play with it and inspect it in your browser. You will see the item is removed from DOM yet gets put back. All using the same button.

**Caveat**: Add a tomato, hide it, add another tomato, and restore the last tomato. What happens?

Nothing serious, yet you will have two list items with `id` that are `tomato-2`. You can establish a global variable to keep count and when you add a new one, use that instead of a count of the list items.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks that is a massive help. Great example, although I have worked a way using a different method.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @twisty that was a massive help. Although I could adjust the code you provided to achieve my goal, it was not the method I had in mind. I understand now that the object needs to come from somewhere.

I used jquery so that on click of a single button, it would check if there is a list item with the id #tomato. If there is, then it removes it, if there isn’t, it adds it.

Thus, the one button remove and append IMG problem is solved.

```
$(function() {
$(".addToms").click(function () {
    if ($("li").is('#tomato'))
       $("li").remove('#tomato');     
    else
        $("ul").prepend('<li class="centerUL" id="tomato"><img src="tomato.jpg"></li>');
    });
});
```

As mentioned in the initial post, this does not use the standard hide/show method. Although there is nothing wrong with that method, the goal here was to manipulate the DOM in such a way that multiple buttons can create a list of fruit images ordered by the user, rather than a static pre determined list in which the order stays the same but the elements are hidden and shown on click.